# Error with repolr: Error in rowSums(t(mapply(complete.cases, split.data))) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, mapply

I am trying to analyse a dataset in R.

The data set looks something like this:

```
ID visit REL_3 LOAN ee dp pa  exer alcohol  e  p  d
1  2     1     4    2 44 12 32 122.0       8  2  0  2
2  2     2     4    2 44 48 75  78.5       8  2  2  2
3  2     3     4    1 26 17 49 222.5       8  1  2  2
4  2     4    NA   NA NA NA NA    NA      NA NA NA NA
5  3     1     4    6 27 13 48  78.0      44  2  2  2
6  3     2     4    6 46 13 37  49.0      38  2  1  2
```

Except for ID and visit, all the variables are numeric.

However when I try to fit:

```
repolr(e~REL_3LOANalcohol*exer, data=mss, categories=3,subjects = "ID",times = c(1,2,3,4),corr.mod = "ar1",alpha=0.5)
```

I get Error

```
Error in rowSums(t(mapply(complete.cases, split.data))) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I would appreciate some help on this if possible. I had to add NAs because the repolr package requires entries for all the patients for all the visits even if there is no data for that particular visit and subject. 
I dont know how to proceed. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Regards,
Shalom